# Error: This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am able to query the in app product and get the SKU details but I can't make the purchase without this error coming up.

I'm a little confused about this... I have uploaded the apk as alpha release in the Google play store. It's signed and its status is PUBLISHED, however in the top right of the Developer Console / APK section it says updates pending.

Am I just to wait for the updates that are pending and then try again? I published this app roughly six hours ago. Since then I have changed my code multiple times in Android Studio. Does the version on Google Play and the version I run on my device have to be exactly the same letter for letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're seeing "updates pending", I am assuming your app or in app products are still not published.

Check if app is in published status under "All Applications" that comes when you click the Android icon on the left on Google Play developer console.

Uploading APK to alpha doesn't make it published. You must fill out the 'Store Listing' and 'Pricing & Distribution' pages.

Comment: i was facing similar issue.. but not on all users.. only some users may be county specfic ,  any way to fix this?  i was used  billing v6 version